# In MonoTouch, how do I assign a custom view to my view controller?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

If I want to use a custom view object with my view controller, instead of just using the one that's initialized by default, can I just assign it to the view controller's View property. For example, is the following the correct/safe approach?

```
public class MyView : UIView
{
}

public class MyController : UIViewController
{
    // Constructors.

    public MyController()
    {
        View = new MyView();
    }
}
```

Seems to work in a simple test, but I don't want to be introducing any time-bombs.

Or, should I be adding my custom view as a subview of the existing view in ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding the custom views as subviews.

```
public class MyView : UIView
{
}

public class MyController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        var myView = new MyView();
        this.View.AddSubview(myView);
    }
}
```